# Does not using references hurt performance in rust?

Tags: performance, optimization, rust

In Rust, I often write code like the `transform` function below. I have some immutable input and return a newly allocated output:

```
// the transform function doesn't modify inp. instead, it returns something new.
fn transform(inp: String) -> String { // with reference: inp: &String

    let buf: Vec<_> = inp.as_bytes().iter().map(|x| x + 1).collect();

    String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf).to_string()
}

// using the transform function
fn main() {
    let msg: String = String::from("HAL9000");

    println!("{}", msg);
    println!("{}", transform(msg)); // with reference: &msg
}
```

Does it hurt performance if I don't use a reference for the `inp` parameter to the `transform` function? Or does the compiler recognize that `inp`, because it's not mutable, can be reused/referenced? Put another way: Is it worth the extra effort to declare immutable input parameters as references, like in C++, to avoid copying huge data structures?

Comment: You could write the alternative with a reference to `inp` and benchmark both to check if you're right.

Comment: It does not hurt performance that you don't take a reference. What _does_ hurt performance is allocating and copying.

Comment: And moving is much stronger than `&`: it means that you won't use this value again. In fact, `&` may hurt performance (not here, because I doubt the compiler will be able to optimize out the allocation here, but there are cases it does).

Comment: `&str` is represented in memory as a pointer and a length; `String` is a pointer, length, and a capacity. So without inlining, yes, not using a reference could slightly hurt performance because it requires passing 3 pointer-size values instead of 2; but the larger issue is (as others have mentioned) if you need to clone a string since you moved it somewhere.

Comment: @Coder-256 It will not be measurable.